# PLSQL query that returns rows when first condition is met

Tags: sql, oracle, case, sql-order-by

I have this query

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE
(test.fee = 30003
AND test.date_from <= TRUNC(to_date('08/03/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'))
AND test.date_until >= TRUNC(to_date('08/03/2020','dd/mm/yyyy')));
```

That return these records
[image]

I need to modify this query to return:

In case any row has single_portfolio = 100000885, return that row only, ELSE return all the other rows. (That is what I meant (edit))

I have tried a lot of approaches and none was working, I think nested selects might be needed.

Thank you.

Comment: The 2nd condition doesn't make sense. Query should contain parameter which decides what to do according to SINGLE_PORTFOLIO column value. OK - if you find row(s) that are equal to parameter value, return them. But, if no rows match, it means that **all** of them should be returned. Presume you enter 100000885 - row #1 is returned. If you enter 123, as there's no match, you said that you'd return rows "where single_portfolio <> 123" and that these are rows #2 and 3. Well, as far as I can tell, the 1st row's single_portfolio is different from 123. Why should it NOT be returned?

Comment: Where is your `certain value` defined? Your two conditions (if used at the same time) would not filter anything.

Comment: You specify two cases, but they are not mutually exclusive and will return all table. Both conditions 1. and 2. are met at the same time. 1. will return matched row. 2. will return all other rows.

Comment: @Littlefoot you are right, I understand what you mean. I actually want to either return the row where the single_portfolio is equal to the given value, Else return all the other ones (The one with the portfolio = given value excluded). That is the logic I'm trying to create.

Comment: @PM77-1 You are absolutely right, certain value is defined in a plsql function, I fetch it before my select query, the thing is, I want to return the row that single_portfolio is equal to the given value, and if not only return the other rows.

Comment: @DimaYankin I understand what you are saying you are right. Is there any way I could return the first row in case single_portfolio = given_value, or the others in case its not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to fetch two result sets depending on whether portfolio exists in table or not, then one option is to **union** two similar queries.

This is SQL*Plus example so I'm using substitution variable. You'd use parameter *as is* in your code (maybe a bind variable - `:par_portfolio`, or just parameter's name if you pass it to a stored procedure - `par_portfolio`).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (fee, date_from, date_until, single_portfolio) as
  2    (select 30003, date '2020-03-05', date '2020-03-08', 1885 from dual union all
  3     select 30003, date '2020-03-05', date '2020-03-09', null from dual union all
  4     select 30003, date '2020-03-05', date '2020-03-11', null from dual
  5    )
  6  -- PAR_PORTFOLIO exists in table
  7  select *
  8  from test a
  9  where fee = 30003
 10    and date '2020-03-08' between date_from and date_until
 11    and single_portfolio = &&par_portfolio
 12    and exists (select null from test where single_portfolio = &&par_portfolio)
 13  union all
 14  -- PAR_PORTFOLIO doesn't exist in table
 15  select *
 16  from test
 17  where fee = 30003
 18    and date '2020-03-08' between date_from and date_until
 19    and (single_portfolio <> &&par_portfolio or single_portfolio is null)
 20    and not exists (select null from test where single_portfolio = &&par_portfolio);
```

Test #1: existing portfolio:

```
Enter value for par_portfolio: 1885

       FEE DATE_FROM DATE_UNTI SINGLE_PORTFOLIO
---------- --------- --------- ----------------
     30003 05-MAR-20 08-MAR-20             1885
```

Test #2: portfolio doesn't exist so query returns all rows:

```
SQL> undefine par_portfolio
SQL> /
Enter value for par_portfolio: 1111

       FEE DATE_FROM DATE_UNTI SINGLE_PORTFOLIO
---------- --------- --------- ----------------
     30003 05-MAR-20 11-MAR-20
     30003 05-MAR-20 09-MAR-20
     30003 05-MAR-20 08-MAR-20             1885

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, here is one way to do it using `order by` and `fetch with ties`:

```
select *
from test
where 
    fee = 30003
    and date_from <= date '2020-08-03'
    and date_until >= date '2020-08-03'
order by case when single_portfolio = ? then 0 else 1 end
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

The question mark represent the value you want to prioritize for `single_portfolio`.

Note that I used literal dates rather than `to_date`, which shortens the syntax. I also remove the superfluous parentheses in the `where` clause.